# Installing a program downloaded as a .tgz

Tags: installation, file-format

How to install a program with the.tgz extention?

Answer (score 12):

- **.tgz** is an archive like zip or rar.
- Right click on the file and select **Extract Here**.
- **cd** to the extracted folder.
- Then type **./configure**
- To install type **make** and then **make install**.
- There will be a **Read me** file with instruction on how to install the file.
- However the installation will differ based on the different packages.
- So before installing the **.tgz** files i would strongly advice you to look at the read me file.
- But installing software not in the software centre can be tricky and will not always work without some advanced knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, if it is a source tgz, it uses makefiles, he has build-essentials installed, meets all the dependencies, and has all the header files ready. It will be much more complex.

Comment: When i type ./configure it says access is denied. how can i rectify it?

Comment: try sudo ./configure (if you trust the file)

Comment: while trying sudo ./configure same error ( permission denied). Even logging as root didn't work..

Comment: some software, like python, requires you to call `make test` and `sudo make install` after `make`

Answer (score 3):

As karthick87 already pointed out [installing software from source tarballs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) can be difficult for less experiences users.

It is always better to have software loaded from a [ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) or install it from a DEB package if this is available. Maybe this is also the case for your software? Then you could use the software center or synaptic for a safe installation. Further reading on how to install software can be found in the [Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware).

Answer (score 1):

A .tgz file is just a compressed file, like a .zip. It can contain anything, so the installation method could be very different from one program to another:

- Quite often they are just source code, awaiting to be compiled, it's usually quite complex, much more than what karthick87 suggested.
- Other times it contains some kind of installer that you should run like windows, like firefox downloaded from mozilla site.
- Sometimes you are expected decompress it to a folder and just run the program from there, this is quite usual with java programs.

There is no a simple rule that will cover all the possibilities. But one thing is always true, programs installed outside the Software Centre are liabilities.