# I need help installing java.

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

Is there anyone on here who knows how to install Java on Ubuntu and is willing to teach me how via teamveiwer? I would greatly appeciate it if you do. I haven't been able to play rs in 7 months. I'm currently useing linux Ubuntu 12.10. Also if someone can teach me how to use tar.gz files that would be awesome. I'm new to linux and I have researched forums, guides, and youtube videos and I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Please don't request volunteers to help you by granting them remote access to your machine. You make yourself a gullible target for malicious usage if you do so. So please try something out, and if you get errors, post them back and also quote the source.

Comment: Hi terry, welcome to askubuntu! Indeed, teamviewer is not a safe way to go. Also try to ask one question at a time or browse the site for answers to your questions, they're there, for sure. Quick search gave me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17532/installing-a-program-downloaded-as-a-tgz and http://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java . If these satisfy you, I suggest closing as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Java is here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java . Also you can find on https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/index.html very useful staff.